# directory structure of ear/war file

Tags: weblogic

can u tell what is the  directory structure of any ear/war file in weblogic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [link to diagram of an ear](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/EAR_Application_Diagram.jpg) in weblogic